# Why is the sum of two algebraic functions algebraic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, analyticity, several-complex-variables

Let $U\subset\mathbb{C}^n$ be a domain. A holomorphic function $f:U\to \mathbb{C}$ is called $\textbf{algebraic}$ if there exists a polynomial $p(x,y)$ in the variables of $U\times \mathbb{C}$ such that $p(x,f(x))=0$.

A more geometric interpretation is that the graph $G_f$ of $f$ is an $\textbf{analytic component}$ of an algebraic set $X$.

My question is: say $f,g$ are two algebraic functions, why is $f+g$ algebraic? It is unclear to me if the roots of $p$ define holomorphic functions, if they define them on all of $U$ etc.

I also have a more general question. Say $f_1,_2:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ and $g:\mathbb{C}^2\to\mathbb{C}$, all three algebraic. (Also I ask about the case where they are defined on some general domain, I just require them to be composable). Why is $g(f_1,f_2):\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ algebraic? Here there is a real issue, that the zariski closure of the graph of $G$ may be bad over some set (say it contains the entire fibre) and $(f_1,f_2)$ may hit this set. So that the graph of the composition is in general $\textbf{NOT}$ an analytic component of $\overline{G_g}\cap (f_1,f_2)(\mathbb{C})\times\mathbb{C}$. However it does seem that the composition is in general algebraic - why?

Thank you very much!

Comment: $a$ is algebraic over $k$ iff $k[a]$ is a finite dimensional $k$-vector space, in which case $k[a]=k(a)$ is a field. If $b$ is also algebraic then $k[a,b]$ is finite dimensional. $k[a+b]$ is a sub vector space so it must be finite dimensional. For the composition, with $f_1=f_1(z)$, use that if $g(x,y)$ is a root of $P(x,y,t)$ then $g(f_1,f_2)$ (if well-defined, ie. if analytic somewhere) is a root of $P(f_1,f_2,t)$, thus algebraic over $\Bbb{C}(z,f_1,f_2)$. If $f_1,f_2$ are algebraic too then $\Bbb{C}(z,f_1,f_2,g(f_1,f_2))$ is a finite dimensional $\Bbb{C}(z)$ vector space.

Comment: Your proof is problematic. The polynomial $P(f_1,f_2,t)$ may be just the zero polynomial, if by chance the coefficients of $t$ (which are polynomials in $f_1,f_2$) in it are polynomial realtions for $f_1,f_2$.

Comment: Note this issue doesn't happen with sum, since $t-f_1-f_2=0$  can never be the zero polynomial - it is monic.

Comment: No because we take $P(x,y,t)\in \Bbb{C}(x,y)[t]_{monic}$. I should have said we need the coefficients of $P(f_1,f_2,t)$ to be analytic somewhere too (if $f_1=f_2$ and $P(x,y,0)=1/(x-y)$  then we'll have some trouble with $P(f_1,f_2,t)$)

Comment: If you force $P$ to be Monic in $t$ then nothing assures you that the coefficients of $P(f_1,f_2,t)$ are meromorphic functions as you yourself write. Infact this issue corresponds exactly to the geometric issue that if $X=\overline{G}$ then $(f_1,f_2)$ may be contained in the set where $X$ contains the entire fibre (zariski closure is meant). Can you explain why you may choose $P$ so this issue doesn't happen?

Answer (score 3):

Let $F=\Bbb C(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ be the field of rational functions $U\to \Bbb C$. If $f$ is algebraic on $U$, the relation $p(x,f(x))$ implies that $f(x)$ is algebraic over $F$: we get that it satisfies a monic polynomial in $F[y]$ after dividing $p(x,y)$ by the leading coefficient of $y$. As both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are algebraic, this implies that $F(f_1(x),f_2(x))$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $F$. As $F(f_1(x)+f_2(x))\subset F(f_1(x),f_2(x))$ is a subspace, it must also be finite dimensional, so $f_1+f_2$ is algebraic over $F$ with minimal polynomial $g(y)$, whose coefficients are rational functions on $U$. After clearing denominators, we recover a polynomial of the form $p'(x,f_1(x)+f_2(x))$, which demonstrates that $f_1+f_2$ is algebraic on $U$.

Your second question has a typo: you want the target of $f_1,f_2$ to be $\Bbb C$, not $\Bbb C^2$. The idea here is similar to the previous paragraph - write $F=\Bbb C(x_1)$, then $f_1,f_2$ are algebraic over $F$, and $g(f_1,f_2)$ is algebraic over $F(f_1,f_2)$ (take the relation $p(x_1,x_2,g(x_1,x_2))$ satisfied by $g$ and plug in for $x_1$ and $x_2$), so the composite extension $F(f_1,f_2,g(f_1,f_2))$ is algebraic over $F$, and thus $g(f_1,f_2)$ satisfies $p(x_1,y)$ via the same construction at the end of the previous paragraph.

As for why we can ignore the "badness" of the closure of the graph, all we need is for our function to satisfy the polynomial relation on a dense set: for then $p(x,f(x))$ is a continuous function which is equal to zero on a dense set and thus zero everywhere by continuity. So "bad fibers" appearing infrequently enough don't invalidate our polynomial relation.

(As an aside, it's interesting to compare these sorts of proofs to the case of semi-algebraic/definable functions: there, the strategy is to use quantifier elimination to write the projection of $(x,f_1(x),f_2(x),f_1(x)+f_2(x))$ in terms of formulas not involving $f_1$ or $f_2$. So somehow algebraicness here is playing the same role that quantifier elimination plays in those theories.)

Comment: This is great, as it shows me where my difficulty is. I am actually interested in $Q$-algebraic functions - functions where one can finde such a polynomial $P$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$. For me the $\textbf{height}$ of such a function is is the height of the algebraic set $\{P=0\}$. I really want to show that the sum\composition of $Q$ algebraic functions are $Q$ algebraic, which follows from your remarks. I also want to bound the height of the sum\composition, and unfortunately I can't see right now how to do that, here the badness does make it difficult for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't really have much to add on the height front - you may wish to ask a new question dealing with that specific issue.

Comment: Actually, I see an issue with your proof, for the composition part. It may well be that the polynomial $p(f_1,f_2,g(f_1,f_2))$ is the zero polynomial, if the coefficients of $p$ happen to be relations of $f_1,f_2$. I don't see a reason why this can't happen if they are composable.

Comment: For instance if $f_1,f_2=0$ and $g=x/(1-sqrt(1+y))$. Then $p(f_1,f_2,g)$ is redundent. Still, of course the composition is algebraic, being just a constant function.

Comment: I'll see what I can think of. In the mean time, that's not composable, so you may wish to adjust your example.

Comment: Why isn't it composable? The branch where $\sqrt{1+0}=1$ is problematic at this point, but if you go around $y=-1$ you reach the branch where $\sqrt{1+0}=-1$, and there you get a nice function defined in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$.

Comment: What do you think about this argument: Say $P(x_1,x_2,y)=a_0(x_1,x_2)y^{d}+...+a_0(x_1,x_2)$. Substitute $x_1=f_1$, $x_2=f_2+\epsilon$, and $y=g(x_1,x_2)$. Now for each $i$ we have $a_i(f_1,f_2+\epsilon)=\epsilon^{k_i}b_i(\epsilon)$ where $b_i$ has coefficients in $\mathbb{C}(x,f_1,f_2)$ and $b_i(0)\neq 0$. By dividing by the smallest power of $\epsilon$ and setting $\epsilon=0$ we get a required relation for $g(f_1,f_2)$. My only issue is that the range of $(f_1,f_2+\epsilon)$ may escape the domain of $g$ but maybe this issue can be solved?